# Dynamic form - how to make select list in the new row accept model data?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, angularjs, forms

How can I pass model from Asp.Net ?

I've been doing it since last wednesday - tried jQuery, learned angular, tried it too and now I'm confused about how to get it done. Also been scouting for 'Dynamic Forms' on SO but they seem to cover only appending new HTML to a site and not this topic.

I'm creating a dynamic form that adds rows on demand.

Each row has 3 types of data:

- select list (I want it to be made of database records that contain
  kinds of a certain item)
- quantity of item as int
- some information as string

I got adding rows right but without the select list. 
When I have only quantity and information the rows are appended without a problem, but when I add select list the buton stops working.

The funny thing is that it works in the 1st instance that is not generated by the click.

I guess the problem comes with passing information from viewmodel(containing database records) into the select list in the buton-appended rows.

Anyone has come across this? I could really use any advice at this moment.

Thanks!

Code mentioned:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "angular";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";

    //changed model to check wether it's model's fault 
    //result is the same as with model
    List<int> list = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 };

    var lista = Model;
}

<h2>Tutaj bedzie test formy zrobionej z angular js</h2>

@*baza -> controller -> json (zapisac najlepiej gdzies)
    -> do angulara -> wypluwa json -> fajnei jakby tego json'a przejal kontroller
    -> przerobil na viewmodel -> baza*@

@*angular form*@

@using (Html.BeginForm(@*"Index", "Session", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal", role = "form" }*@))
{
}


<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="addRow">


    <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="addLine()">Dodaj przycisk</button>


    <form method="post" controller="Session" action="pass">





        <div class="listaRekordow">

            <div class="row">
                <div>
                    KLASY. SELECT LIST.
                    <select>
                        <option value="default" selected>Wybierz klase...</option>
                        @*tutaj foreach z przekazanego modelu*@


                        @foreach (var item in list)
                        {
                            <option value=@item> @item.ToString() </option>
                        }

                    </select>
                </div>
                <div>
                    ILOSC
                    <input type="number" value="" />
                </div>
                <div>
                    UWAGI
                    <input type="text" value="" />
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
        <div class="przyciski">
            <div class="row">
                PRZYCISKI
                <input type="submit" value="" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>

</div>

@*angular script*@
<script>




    var app = angular.module("myApp", []);

    app.controller("addRow", function ($scope) {
        $scope.class = {};
        $scope.quantity = {};
        $scope.notice = {};

        $scope.addLine = function () {
            var myHtml = [
'<div class="row">',
'            <div>',
'                KLASY. SELECT LIST.',
'                <select>',
'                    <option selected>Wybierz klase...</option>',
'                    @*tutaj foreach z przekazanego modelu*@',
'                  @foreach (var item in list)
                {
                          <option value=@item> @item.ToString() </option>
            }',

        '                </select>',
        '            </div>',
        '            <div>',
        '                ILOSC',
        '                <input type="number" value=""/>',
        '            </div>',
        '            <div>',
        '                UWAGI',
        '                <input type="text" value=""/>',
        '            </div>',
        '        </div>'
            ].join('');

            $('.listaRekordow').append(myHtml);


        };

    });

    app.controller("passForm", function ($scope, $http) {
        $http.post("/Session/angular", $scope); //przekazuje scope jak wynik formularzu
    });


</script>
```

Comment: now when I think about it will check razor syntax nested in select div

Comment: from what I've learned the problem might be with the HtmlHelper (server side) and that appending is client side